# top 10 scorers by season

Tags: mysql, sql

How I can get top 10 scorers by seasons.

So it shows last season top 10 scorers...

I've tryed left join into table, but it goes broken showing 2 player and counts all goals to first player.

My sqlfiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5d0a78/1

Answer (score 0):

You got it almost right.

You want to group `match_goals` by player ID (`match_player_id`), but then you should **not** select `goal_minute` or any other **per goal** data.

After grouping by player, then you can create a column for `COUNT(match_player_id)` this will give you the number of goals, you can also use this column to order the results.

Your joins and conditions are correct I think.

---

### EDIT

I think your schema needs a few tweaks: check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5a75b/2

Basically create direct relations in the `match_players` and `match_goals` to the other tables.

Comment: Aren't you missing a relationship between `match_goals` and `matches` ?

Comment: Sorry, I might not have a clear answer. I think it would be much easier if you create a unique ID for each player, then use that in the `match_goals` table. Instead of the "mixed" id of `match_player_id`.

Comment: I hope this is helpful: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5a75b/2 but check the changes in the schema. `match_goals` now has direct relation with `matches`, `teams` and `players` (which I think makes sense), also `match_players` is now just a relational table.

Answer (score 0):

I think the query you want looks like this:

```
SELECT p.*, count(*) as num_goals
FROM match_goals g INNER JOIN 
     match_players p
     ON g.match_player_id = p.id INNER JOIN
     matches m
     ON m.id = p.match_id
WHERE p.is_deleted = 0 AND 
      g.is_own_goal = 0 AND
      m.seasion_id = <last season id>
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY num_goals DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Note that the teams table is not needed.  The `SELECT p.*` is allowed because `p.id` (the `GROUP BY` key) is unique.

Comment: But I think he needs this but per-season.